# Increase a pointer's LSB bits but keep the rest (hardcoded ringbuffer size)

Tags: c

i try to code a very compact ringbuffer. The buffer holds 2^X values (X: 1-7) What i need is to increase the X bits (LSB) but keep the rest of the variables. Ive got a solution but i dont know if this works (never modified the pointer address before) and its not so compact. Any idea how to improve this?

```
        // hardcoded ringbuffersize for better ram usage
        // this frees us out, start, end, size variables
        // 7 == 128, 6 == 64
        #define LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_BITS 7
        #define LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_SIZE (1<<LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_BITS)
        // thatswhy we cant use 256 buffer size

        #define LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_DISABLED LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_SIZE+1
        // save new data
        *Buffer->In = Data;

        // save LSB bits
        uint8_t pointermask = Buffer->In;
        // discard all LSB bits
        Buffer->In >>= LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_BITS;
        Buffer->In <<= LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_BITS;
        // save the LSB bits + 1
        Buffer->In |= ++pointermask & (LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_SIZE - 1)

        Buffer->Count++;
```

Comment: If `Buffer->In` is really a pointer type, this code will fail to compile.

Comment: "I dont know if this works" - why don't you try testing it first, and *then* ask a question once you know what behaviour you're getting?

Comment: Use a pointer for the buffers base-address, and some integer-type (char suffices) for the index.

Comment: Yes its not compiling error: invalid operands to binary >> (have ‘uint8_t *’ and ‘int’). the base address pointer would work, but i only have 500 bytes ram, i cannot do this. Then i need another currentIndex variable. So i have to modify the pointer address.

Comment: int x = ((int)buffer->in) & ~((1<<BITS)-1); // zero lower BITS bits. x |= (((int)buffer->in)+1)&((1<<BITS)-1);buffer->in=(void*)x;  Sorry for not bothering minimizing paranthesis etc using the correct variables etc... I assume int and the buffer pointer variables have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what a simple ring buffer implementation looks like.  The size of the ring buffer is determined by the `MASK`.  The value for `MASK` must be 2<sup>n</sup>-1, where `n <= 8`.  For a 256 byte ring buffer, you can eliminate the mask altogether.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MASK 7

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t head;
    uint8_t tail;
    uint8_t data[MASK + 1];
}
    stRingBuffer;

stRingBuffer ringBuffer = { 0, 0 };

// returns true if successful, false if the ring buffer is full
// the argument is the byte that is to be stored in the buffer
bool WriteToRingBuffer( stRingBuffer *buffer, uint8_t data )
{
    uint8_t nextHeadValue = (buffer->head + 1) & MASK;
    if ( nextHeadValue == buffer->tail )
        return( false );

    buffer->data[buffer->head] = data;
    buffer->head = nextHeadValue;
    return( true );
}

// returns a byte from the ring buffer, or 0 if the buffer is empty
// the caller is responsible for making sure the buffer is not empty before calling this function
uint8_t ReadFromRingBuffer( stRingBuffer *buffer )
{
    uint8_t data = 0;

    if ( buffer->tail != buffer->head )
    {
        data = buffer->data[buffer->tail];
        buffer->tail = (buffer->tail + 1) & MASK;
    }

    return( data );
}

// returns the number of items currently in the ring buffer
int itemCountInRingBuffer( stRingBuffer *buffer )
{
    return( (buffer->head - buffer->tail) & MASK );
}

int main( void )
{
    uint8_t data = 31;

    // move the head and tail to a non-zero location in the buffer for testing
    // this demonstrates proper handling of index wrap-around
    ringBuffer.head = 5;
    ringBuffer.tail = 5;

    // fill the buffer up
    while ( WriteToRingBuffer( &ringBuffer, data ) )
    {
        printf( "Wrote %u, buffer now has %d items\n", data, itemCountInRingBuffer( &ringBuffer ) );
        data++;
    }

    // empty the buffer out
    while ( ringBuffer.tail != ringBuffer.head )
    {
        data = ReadFromRingBuffer( &ringBuffer );
        printf( "Read %u, there are %d items remaining\n", data, itemCountInRingBuffer( &ringBuffer ) );
    }
}
```

Note that if you intend to use a ring buffer to pass data between threads, or from an interrupt routine to the background code, then you either need to use the appropriate locking mechanisms, or you need to become an expert in lockless multi-threading.

Comment: The problem with this is that i need to pass the data as pointer. I need to store it outside the buffer library. Adding a base pointer + head + tail is another byte of ram. The problem is i only have 500 bytes but lots of flash so i need this optimization. a current in pointer + count would be enough if someone can tell me how to modify the pointers address. the pointer (Buffer->IN) holds uint8_t variables and has the predefined size so i dont overwrite any other ram.

Comment: Actually, I passed `data` as a pointer in the `ReadFromRingBuffer` function so that I could use the return value to indicate success/failure. If you don't want to pass `data` as a pointer, then you can check that `head != tail` before calling `ReadFromRingBuffer`, and then implement the function as `uint8_t ReadFromRingBuffer( void )`.  In other words, return the data from the function.

Comment: oh, i think there was a * missing in the write function. however i want to avoid head AND tail. i want to save the pointer + the count. cant we get this working? otherwise i have to pass the buffer itself everytime. it might sound weird what i try to do, but if its possible, this would be cool

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking is how to increment a pointer in a wrapping manner, the answer is very simple. You will need to replace the uint64_t type cast to the size of pointers on your platform. The second statement wraps the pointer if all lower bits are zero.

```
p ++;
p -= ((uint64_t) p) & (LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_SIZE - 1) ?
    0 : LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_SIZE;
```

Or alternatively, again replacing the type casts with the appropriate ones

```
p = (uint8_t *) (((uint64_t) p & ~(LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_SIZE - 1)) |
                 (((uint64_t) p + 1) & (LIGHTWEIGHT_RING_BUFFER_SIZE - 1)));
```

Comment: I'm on an 8bit system but this could work. Something simple like this i was searching for. Thx!

Comment: Then replace uint64_t with uint8_t.